# I use npm wkhtmltopdf in node.js, I get an error

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf

By setting the path, the pdf conversion function in cmd also works fine.
Why do I get the following error in node.js?

### Using the other options is the same error.

Error: Error: spawn wkhtmltopdf ENOENT
    at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\khj\React_androidProjects\restAPIchecklist\node_modules\wkhtmltopdf\index.js:161:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! restapichecklist@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the restapichecklist@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\khj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-05T05_27_53_709Z-debug.log

->>>

### debug.log Contents

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'E:\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\khj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]

```
router.get('/pdfbox', (req, res) => {
  wkhtmltopdf('https://www.google.com/', { output: './data/exlist.pdf' });
});
```

Comment: Is wkhtmltopdf installed on your system? Can you run it directly via command line (i.e. is it within your PATH variable)? and var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf'); in top of js file?

Comment: 1. C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf.
2. npm install wkhtmltopdf --save.  
I did this.
->In the Project node module, there are three index.js, package.json, and readme.md.

Comment: Be sure the wkhtmltopdf command line tool is in your PATH when you're done installing. If you don't want to do this for some reason, you can change the require('wkhtmltopdf').command property to the path to the wkhtmltopdf command line tool.

Comment: path was set. But I get the same error.

Comment: Can you run wkhtmltopdf from your terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool on your system.

The easiest way to do this is to [download](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable) a prebuilt version for your system. DO NOT try to use the packages provided by your distribution as they may not be using a patched Qt and have missing features.

Finally, to install the node module, use npm:

```
npm install wkhtmltopdf --save
```

Be sure the wkhtmltopdf command line tool is in your PATH when you're done installing. If you don't want to do this for some reason, you can change the require('wkhtmltopdf').command property to the path to the wkhtmltopdf command line tool.

Then ensure the bin folder is on your PATH. C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin is the default installation path. Verify that it is correct for your machine.

in index.js add this command:

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
router.get('/pdfbox', (req, res) => {
  wkhtmltopdf('https://www.google.com/', { output: './data/exlist.pdf' });
});
```

add PATH in windows: [windows](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)

add PATH in linux : [linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux)

Comment: Can I add "C: \ Program Files \ wkhtmltopdf \ bin" to the path like this? and ("the wkhtmltopdf command line tool is in your PATH when you're done installing")->
I do not get what it means.

Comment: running wkhtmltopdf from your terminal or cmd!